# How do you manage tag schema evolution in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags

We like I'm sure many of you have a well-defined set of tagging standards that apply to various cloud resources which we typically provision via IaC pipelines using Terraform. Periodically though some or all of those standard tags change and naturally we want to *update* the tag values on some or all of our many thousands of resources.

At the moment our code base supplies tags as input variables for each deployment and we'll use code like

```
default_tags {
  tags = var.tags
}
```

or via dynamic blocks for resources like autoscaling groups.
If we want to update those tags for a significant number of deployments though we would currently have to run many individual pipelines, so I'm wondering how other people deal with this issue programatically. My search-fu only really returns results for the question "How do I add tags dynamically at resource creation time" which isn't really our challenge.

I imagine I'll need something like a git repo of standard tags to allow people to update the schema, a store of "current configuration" something like parameter store and a pipeline to "deploy" tags whenever there's an update, but if this is already a solved problem I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.